# Which one of the following is true

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let, $f_n(x)$ , for $n\geq 1$, be a sequence of continuous non-negative functions on $[0,1]$ such that
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 f_n(x)\,dx = 0$.
Which of the following is correct :

A. $f_n \rightarrow 0$ uniformly on $[0,1]$.

B. $f_n$ may not converge uniformly but converges to 0 pointwise.

C. $f_n$ will converge pointwise and the limit may be non-zero.

D. $f_n$ is not guaranteed to have a pointwise limit.

Which one is true?? Please EXPLAIN.

Comment: Please share your thoughts on the problem, and explain what you've tried.

Comment: @Priyadarshi : Are you using some web site or style guide to guide your MathJax code?  I've seen some of this same weird style of MathJax coding in other stackexchange posts lately and I'm wondering where it's coming from.  If you ever want to learn proper use of LaTeX, look at my edits.

Comment: ya, I m taking help from other websites... but seems to me it is all right..isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the following example:

$$
f_n(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{cll}
x^n & \text{if} & \text{$n$ odd}, \\
(1-x)^n & \text{if} & \text{$n$ even}.
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Then $f_n(x)\ge 0$, for all $x\in[0,1]$ and $n\in\mathbb N$, and $\int_0^1 f_n(x)\,dx=1/n\to 0$. $\{f_n(x)\}$ converges pointwise to zero, for all $x\in(0,1)$, but it does not converge for $x=0,1$.

Clearly, the answer in D.

Answer (score 1):

$D$ is true.  If we didn't need continuous, the standard counter example is the "typewriter function". Let

$f_1 = 1,\\ f_2= \chi_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]},\\ f_3 = \chi_{[\frac{1}{2},1]},\\ f_4 = \chi_{[0,\frac{1}{4}]}
\\f_5 =\chi_{[\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}]}\\ \cdots$

and so on. There is no pointwise limit, since given any $x$, then $f(x)$ will be $0$ and $1$ infinitely many times.  However, the limit of integrals is $0$, since the integral in this case is just the size of the interval of the characteristic function, which looks like $2^{-n}$

To make this argument work for the continuous function, just consider triangles on these intervals, say the triangle with height $1$ and base $2^{-n}$ going from left to right as the $f_i$ do.